# Displaying remote URL

Tags: html

First I must explain I am a total newbie with regards to web design.

My question is as follows:

I would like to have a remote URL displayed through a different web server. The remote URL resides on an internal firewalled server and I would like to give public access to a single page by displaying it on a remote web server that has access to the firewalled page. I have tried iframes but they use the clients IP which results in the page failing to display. I have limited access to the server (CPanel) - please advise how this is possible? The remote URL will be requiring a login - not sure if this will have relevance on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a page which makes a request to the firewalled page using either CURL or HttpWebRequest or any compatible technology based on the platform you have chosen. It can then trim out the headers and other tags which are not required and render the html in a div, or it can just redirect the entire code in the response of your page.

This way, there will be no connection made from the client end, just your server will connect to your firewalled server and fetch the page from there and in turn give it back.

The only problem here is, forms - images and linked objects might not work properly, you might also have to parse them and replace the respective urls to point to your server which in turn proxyfy it.

Here is an example of it

https://proxify.net/